# laravel pusher run very slow

Tags: php, laravel, performance, pusher

I followed this tutorial:
[BUILD A CHAT APP WITH LARAVEL](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/)

But the `broadcast()` and `event()` functions act very slow as 2~8 seconds when I track time duration in the php Controller. No Error messages launched by the way.

I guess it is not normal case, isn't websocket should works real-time? Even I changed DEBUG to true or false didn't change this.

I don't have an idea how fast laravel+pusher should be. They are just called as 'real-time', shouldn't they run in 0.0something second?

Could anyone give advice please?

** I just test it again. The broadcast time is ~0.8 second, and the whole duration from client sending POST to client's Listener handled broadcast is around 1 second.
Sorry I can't reproduce the slow performance happened yesterday.
Is this performance normal for Pusher? thanks!!

```
env:
Laravel Framework 5.6.28
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 5.0.1)
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 5.1.0)
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 5.2.0)
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 6.1.0)

php "^7.1.3"
barryvdh/laravel-debugbar   "^3.1"
fideloper/proxy "^4.0"
laravel/framework   "5.6.*"
laravel/tinker  "^1.0"
pusher/pusher-php-server    "^3.1"
```

below is my code:

```
<?php
//Controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Events\MessageSent;
use Debugbar as Debugbar;

class ChatsController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show chats
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
  return view('chat');
}

/**
 * Fetch all messages
 *
 * @return Message
 */
public function fetchMessages()
{
  return Message::with('user')->get();
}

/**
 * Persist message to database
 *
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
$t2 = microtime(true);
    $user = Auth::user();
//        DebugBar::info($user);

//$message = $user->messages()->create(['message' => $request->input('message')]);
$message = $user->messages()->create(['message' => $request->input('message')]);

DebugBar::info("logic time:");
DebugBar::info(microtime(true) - $t2);
//    $m = new Message(['message' => $request->input('message')]);
//    $user->messages()->create($message);
//    DebugBar::info($message);
$t1 = microtime(true);
//        broadcast(new MessageSent($user,$message));
        event(new MessageSent($user,$message));
DebugBar::info("broadcast time:");
DebugBar::info(microtime(true) - $t1);
  return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
}

    public function clearMessage(){
        $u = Auth::user();
        $m = $u->messages();
        $m->delete();
    }
}

<?php
//Event
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;

use App\User;
use App\Message;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
/**
 * The name of the queue on which to place the event.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $broadcastQueue = 'your-queue-name';

    /**
     * User that sent the message
     *
     * @var User
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * Message details
     *
     * @var Message
     */
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
//    public function __construct(User $user, Message $message)
public function __construct(User $user, Message $message)
        {
        $this->user = $user;
//        $this->message = 'this is a message from MessageSent Class';
        $this->message = $message;
    }

 /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat');
    }
}

<?php
// User
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
 * A user can have many messages
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }

}

<?php
//Message
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    //

    /**
 * Fields that are mass assignable
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['message'];

/**
 * A message belong to a user
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

//....

     // chat example
Vue.component('chat-messages', require('./components/ChatMessages.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-form', require('./components/ChatForm.vue'));


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */


let vm = new Vue({
 el:'#app',
 data:{
     name:'root',
//
// ...
//
// chat example
     messages: [],
 },

 created(){
      // chat example
        this.fetchMessages();
     window.Echo.private('chat')
          .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
            console.log('listened:');
            console.log(e);
            this.messages.push({
              message: e.message.message,
              user: e.user
        });
  });

 },
 mounted(){


 },
 methods:{
//
//...
//
// chat example
        fetchMessages() {
            axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
                this.messages = response.data;
            });
        },

        addMessage(message) {
//            this.messages.push(message);

            axios.post('/messages', message).then(response => {
              console.log('Post response:');
              console.log(response.data);
            });
        }

 },
 components:{
     'top-nav-p': topNavP,
     'slide-0': homeComponent,
     'slide-1':gameListComponent,
 }
});
```

```html
<!-- resources/views/chat.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Chats</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <chat-messages v-bind:messages="messages"></chat-messages>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <chat-form
                        v-on:messagesent="addMessage"
                        :user="{{ Auth::user() }}"
                    ></chat-form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

```
// resources/assets/js/components/ChatMessages.vue

<template>
    <ul class="chat">
        <li class="left clearfix" v-for="message in messages">
            <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                <div class="header">
                    <strong class="primary-font">
                        {{ message.user.name }}
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <p>
                    {{ getTime(message.message) }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['messages'],
    methods: {
        getTime(m){
            return (performance.now()-m);
        }

    },
  };
</script>

// resources/assets/js/components/ChatForm.vue

<template>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="btn-input" type="text" name="message" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." v-model="newMessage" @keyup.enter="sendMessage">

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" @click="sendMessage">
                Send
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['user'],

        data() {
            return {
                newMessage: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            sendMessage() {
                this.$emit('messagesent', {
                    user: this.user,
                    message: performance.now(),//this.newMessage
                });
                this.newMessage = ''
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I find out the `default` in `queue.php` point to `sync`, which is only for dev.
After changing the `default` to `database` which is for production,
the function `broadcast()` change to around 0.01 seconds.

Thanks for reading.